# how to add text on 5 span that uses same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i add a text to all 5 spans that share the same id.

the html goes:

```
<div class="body">
<form>
<span id = "test" ></span>
<span id = "test" ></span>
<span id = "test" ></span>
<span id = "test" ></span>
<span id = "test" ></span>
</form>
</div>
```

The js:

```
function check_aff_payment(elem){

        $(elem).find('#test').each(function(){
            $("#test").text("*");
        });

}
```

Comment: id in a HTML page are supposed to be unique

Comment: You should be using a class, not an ID. An ID is just that, an ID, and should be unique.

Comment: so if i were to use class, it would then apply the text to all that have the same classes?

Comment: How can you check a <span> ?

Comment: Also what is this ":checked" attribute supposed to do to a span.

Comment: sorry about that. that refers to a different action that will trigger the adding of the text to the span, removed it to avoid confusion

Comment: IDs ***MUST*** be (yes, in bold italic caps) **UNIQUE**. Always. It will cause all kind of problems if they aren't. Especially when involving selector lookups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ID's** on a `HTML` page are required to be unique.

Try using `class` instead

```
<div class="body">
   <form>
      <span class="test"></span>
      <span class="test"></span>
      <span class="test"></span>
      <span class="test"></span>
      <span class="test"></span>
   </form>
</div>

function check_aff_payment(elem){
    $(elem).find('.test').each(function(){
       $(this).text("*");
    });
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wdy5P/1/)**

Comment: nevermind the checked, it was another functionality.

also it works, will accept your answer when the time limit is up.